# Toolkit.getImage() from src folder

Tags: java

I am trying to get an image from the src/ folder in a package, however I am not having any success.

```
nekoPics[i] = tk.getImage(getClass().getResource(String.format("resources/pracs/neko/%s", nekosrc[i])));
```

Anyone sugestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it being copied into wherever your code is being built? Being in the `src` directory doesn't help if at execution time the class is in a `bin` directory (or a jar file).

Also note that if your class is in a package, then `Class.getResource` will work relative to that package by default. So if your package is foo.bar, it'll be looking for `foo/bar/resources/pracs/neko/whatever`. If you want to make it absolute, you could either use `ClassLoader.getResource`, or put a leading `/` at the start of your string:

```
String resource = String.format("/resources/pracs/neko/%s", nekosrc[i]);
nekoPics[i] = tk.getImage(getClass().getResource(resource));
```

or

```
String resource = String.format("resources/pracs/neko/%s", nekosrc[i]);
nekoPics[i] = tk.getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource));
```

Of course, if the `reousrces` directory is *actually* relative to your package, you shouldn't do that :)

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks, but how is class loader getting the resources from the correct path? What is the typical way of handling image resources in Java? like where do you put them in the project?

Comment: @Alex: It depends on your build environment - I'm sure there are lots of ways of doing it. The class loader knows about a logical "root", that's all.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `getClass().getResource()` with a relative path (i.e. one not starting with `/`), then the path will be interpreted as *relative to the package of the class* you're using to load the resource.

So if you have that code in the class `mypackage.MyClass`, then requesting `resources/pracs/neko/something` will actually try to find `mypackage/resources/pracs/neko/something` relative to your classpath.